# Draggable MapKit Annotations

Tags: mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am working with MapKit on MacOS and trying to enable a draggable annotation that uses a custom image. I can successfully get the annotation to be draggable but it requires the user to be quite accurate with where they click and drag as the annotation image is larger than a conventional pin. Is there a simple way to expand the area so that any part of the image is draggable? Otherwise I imagine I will have to use some kind of NSGesture on the view to manually set the dragstate, but was hoping there might be an easier way!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I never managed to sort this to my satisfaction using Annotations. I’m not saying it can’t be done, maybe someone else can comment and leave pointers to help. But I eventually achieved what I wanted using overlays instead. So if someone stumbles on this question and has the same issue, you can make it work with a custom overlay rather than an annotation and you implement the dragging using a NSPanGestureRecognizer with translation for the movement.